# How does Perl's grep function work with a regex?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

How does the following grep function works (what does `!/0o1Iil]/` do? )

```
@chars = grep !/0o1Iil]/, 0..9, "A".."Z", "a".."z"; 
use Data::Dumper; 
print Dumper @chars;
```

to produce the following in @chars?

```
$VAR1 = 0;
$VAR2 = 1;
$VAR3 = 2;
$VAR4 = 3;
$VAR5 = 4;
$VAR6 = 5;
$VAR7 = 6;
$VAR8 = 7;
$VAR9 = 8;
$VAR10 = 9;
$VAR11 = 'A';
$VAR12 = 'B';
$VAR13 = 'C';
$VAR14 = 'D';
$VAR15 = 'E';
$VAR16 = 'F';
$VAR17 = 'G';
$VAR18 = 'H';
$VAR19 = 'I';
$VAR20 = 'J';
$VAR21 = 'K';
$VAR22 = 'L';
$VAR23 = 'M';
$VAR24 = 'N';
$VAR25 = 'O';
$VAR26 = 'P';
$VAR27 = 'Q';
$VAR28 = 'R';
$VAR29 = 'S';
$VAR30 = 'T';
$VAR31 = 'U';
$VAR32 = 'V';
$VAR33 = 'W';
$VAR34 = 'X';
$VAR35 = 'Y';
$VAR36 = 'Z';
$VAR37 = 'a';
$VAR38 = 'b';
$VAR39 = 'c';
$VAR40 = 'd';
$VAR41 = 'e';
$VAR42 = 'f';
$VAR43 = 'g';
$VAR44 = 'h';
$VAR45 = 'i';
$VAR46 = 'j';
$VAR47 = 'k';
$VAR48 = 'l';
$VAR49 = 'm';
$VAR50 = 'n';
$VAR51 = 'o';
$VAR52 = 'p';
$VAR53 = 'q';
$VAR54 = 'r';
$VAR55 = 's';
$VAR56 = 't';
$VAR57 = 'u';
$VAR58 = 'v';
$VAR59 = 'w';
 $VAR60 = 'x';
 $VAR61 = 'y';
 $VAR62 = 'z';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the [grep perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html). The statement in your example is using the `grep EXPR,LIST` syntax, which means any Perl expression can take the place of `EXPR`.

grep takes the list provided to it, and returns only the items where EXPR is true.

EXPR in this case is `! /0o1Iil]/` (space added for readability) which means "this item is *not* matched by the regex `/0o1Iil]/`.  Since none of those items are matched by that regular expression (none of them contain the string `0o1Iil]`) they are all returned.

As other posters have mentioned, the regex was probably supposed to read `/[0o1Iil]/`, which would remove characters that could be confused, e.g. 0 and o, 1 and I. This sounds useful for passwords or serial numbers, etc.

Btw, you could rewrite the grep into the clearer BLOCK form, and make the LIST construction explicit:

```
@chars = grep { ! /[0o1Iil]/ } (0..9, 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z');
```

Comment: This example really looks like there was supposed to be an open bracket, so that the grep would match everything except the 0, o, 1, I, i, and l.

Comment: Yes, sounds like this was designed to generate passwords or serial numbers etc. where ambiguous characters should not be present.

Comment: yes I missed the opening square bracket. thanks for the answer.

Comment: and yes this was designed to generate passwords.

Answer (score 2):

`//` is a regular expression match operator. `!/[0o1Iil]/` means “does not match any of the characters in the square brackets.” And I think you’re missing an opening square bracket (`[`) after the first slash – the intention is to filter out all characters that could be mistaken for some other (0/O, I/l/1).

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax of a Perl grep is:

```
grep BLOCK LIST
```

It evaluates the `BLOCK` for each element of `LIST` and returns the list value consisting of those elements for which the expression evaluated to true.

In your case `BLOCK` is `!/0o1Iil]/` which return true for those elements which do not contain the pattern `0o1Iil]`. Since in your case none of the `LIST` elements contain that pattern, the grep returns entire `LIST`.

Had the `BLOCK` been like: `!/[0o1Iil]/` which returns true for those elements which ***do not contain a zero, or a lowercase o, or a 1, or a I, or a i or a l***, then you would have got a `LIST` with all but these elements as the result.

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` function acts as a filter on lists.

In this case, the list is all alphanumeric characters.

The filter is specified by a regular expression. The `!` denotes `not`. In other words, the resulting list should exclude whatever items match the regular expression.

The regular expression is trying to match any occurrence of `0o1Iil]` (not `0o1Iil`, because omitting a `[` at the beginning of the set will prevent the regular expression from seeing the `]` as the *character class* metacharacter.

**`grep {not /0o1Iil]/} 0..9, A..Z, a..z` (Without the `[`):**

Seeing that the list `0..9, A..Z, a..z` contains no occurrence of `0o1Iil]`, there are no items to filter out, which is why you get your entire list of alphanumeric characters back.

**`grep {not /[0o1Iil]/} 0..9, A..Z, a..z` (With the `[`):**

Any items in the list matching `0`, `o`, `1`, `I`, `i` or `l` will be filtered out. Thus, you'll get your alphanumeric list back, sans the above-mentioned six characters.